# How not to lose superscript formatting when saving to .png, KableExtra in R

Tags: r, save, png, kableextra, superscript

I have 'Superscript text' in the title of my table  and it works when viewing.

Here is the example:

```
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)

iris[1:10, ] %>% #selecting line 1 to 10 
  kable(caption = "Exemple$^{SuperScriptText}$") %>%  # Using 'superscript' in the title
  kable_classic()  # classic theme
```

[image]

But, when saving in .png, Superscript formatting is lost. The code text appears instead: Exemple$^{SuperScriptText}$

```
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)

iris[1:10, ] %>% #selecting line 1 to 10 
  kable(caption = "Exemple$^{SuperScriptText}$") %>%  # Using 'superscript' in the title
  kable_classic()  %>% # classic theme
  save_kable("test_save.png") # Exporting in png format
```

[image]
How to keep the superscript when exporting?

Comment: Did not work. Do you have any other suggestions, please?

Comment: I still couldn't find a solution

Comment: I tried, but it seems to have some limitations.  Have you tried other packages

Comment: Which would you suggest, please?

Comment: You may try with `formattable`, `flextable` etc